# How SetTimeout Function's Time parameter works in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
 for ( var d = 0; d < 3; d++ )
        (function(d)
        {
            setTimeout(
                    function()
                    {
                        console.log( "Value of d: ", d );
                        console.log( d == d, "Check the value of d." );
                    }, d * 200);
        })(d);
```

How the time parameter(d) is working? setTimeout inside of for loop. Confusion to use SetTimeout within for loop.

Comment: the core concept is the use of a closure variable in a loop - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: and [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work fine.

But if you are rather trying to understand it, you can end up picking up an import trade of JS.. **Closures**

So first run it like this

```
for ( var d = 0; d < 3; d++ )       
      setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log( "Value of d: ", d );
                    console.log( d == d, "Check the value of d." );
                }, d * 200);
```

The output :

```
Value of d:  3 
true "Check the value of d." 
Value of d:  3 
true "Check the value of d." 
Value of d:  3 
true "Check the value of d."
```

Did you notice the non incremented value of `d`? This is because the value of `d` becomes 3 before any of the setTimeout function is actually executed. So what you need are three copies of `d` with the value 1,2,3.

This can be achieved with executing an immediate function & saving the value of `d` at the time of defining the setTimeout function itself. What we essentially do is wrap each call inside a scope where `d` is accessible later (after setTimeout functions kick off).

Hence your code:

```
for ( var d = 0; d < 3; d++ ) (function(d) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log( "Value of d: ", d );
                        console.log( d == d, "Check the value of d." );
                    }, d * 200);
        })(d);
```

produces output :

```
Value of d:  0
true "Check the value of d."
Value of d:  1
true "Check the value of d."
Value of d:  2
true "Check the value of d."
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you should understand `(function(arg){})(d)` defines an anonymous function and immediataly call it with an argument `d`

Comment: yes i know this but how d is comming and when it ill be get cause 100 in time

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, `d` was declared in for loop: `for(var d = 0; d < 3; d++)` @MohammadFaizankhan